# Exchange Admin Audit log

Tags: exchange-2010, logging, audit

i was looking at the admin audit logs today and found it  very usefull. But it doesn't include the source computer launching the commands.

An example, i have the EMC on my computer modifying some distribution list on exchange which is a different machine.
In the logs it will say source as being the exchange server and not my computer.

Is there a way to change taht? or have more details?

Thanks